# Proof of inclusion for odd-valued tree

Tags: hash

How would a proof of inclusion be done here as the number of nodes is odd and some hashes don't have a sibling hash?
Normally you would send the sibling for each level to the client.

Here there are none, is the proof of inclusion not possible here, or do you just send the parent, until you reach a node that has a sibling? But what would the client calculate then?

Comment: Are we talking about the Merkle Trees?

Comment: Yes merkle tree.

Comment: I'm lazy to draw a figure, however, if you look at a heap ( a special binary tree), it is easy to achieve a Merkle tree of size not equal to $2^n$ for some integer $n$.